# How to make a price filtering with range in react js

Tags: range, filtering

Have any codes are available .please send me those resources. I am trying to find the answer.
the range price filtering will be this type https://www.gozayaan.com/hotel/list?checkin=2022-04-24&checkout=2022-04-25&search=&location=601135&rooms=1,2,0&child_ages=&sort=POPULARITY&fbclid=IwAR3sUZPOJ0Pr80stSvvpVYwVF9JepAyIe670wZ-HWwdl46Yp8I7e29P8Gto